# How can I wield two swords in prehensile tails?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Is there a feat tree I could take that would allow me to wield two custom made katana using multiple prehensile tails? (The multiple prehensile tails are already taken care of by a custom race in our campaign.)

I am trying to do this without refluffing any rules.

Comment: Maybe: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/multiweapon-fighting-combat

Comment: Is "with little to no penalties" a requirement? What do you define as "little to no"?

Comment: @JonathanHobbs I removed that part. I am willing to take penalties.

Comment: @ColinD That applies to actual arms and hands. I am looking for as read feats that will allow this.

Comment: @Aaron What is the source of your multiple tails?

Comment: @ColinD Racial. It is a custom race.

Comment: If you are playing a custom race, then I think the answer to this question is also a custom solution, something that is probably only going to be determined by your DM.  If you're looking for existing rules for prehensile tails to base this off of, Colin D's answer below should work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

You have prehensile tails, not extra arms. Whenever a player has prehensile tails (with regards to non-custom content), it comes along with the following text (taken from the [Teifling race](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedRaceGuide/featuredRaces/tieflings.html)):

> While they cannot wield weapons with their tails, they can use them to retrieve small, stowed objects carried on their persons as a swift action

There are no feats that allow you to change this shortcoming of your tail

Comment: Well, almost everything.  The Monk of the Four Winds can technically wield weapons in his prehensile tail when channeling the Monkey Aspect, but that's probably an oversight.